# How can I add exception handling without skiping into the next input function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
valid_Total = 120

def get_num(n):
    inp = -1
    while input not in range(121):
        try:
            inp = int(input(f"Enter your total {n} credits : "))
            if inp not in range(121):
                print("Out of range")
            else:
                pass
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a integer")
        return inp


while True:
    x = get_num("PASS")
    y = get_num("DEFER")
    z = get_num("FAIL")
    if x+y+z != valid_Total:
        print("Incorrect Total")
    else:
        break
```

How can I fix the exception handling so when I input anything other than a integer it ask to enter the value again to the same variable without procceeding it onto the next variable?

Comment: General comment, if you have `else` block with pass, just remove it. Also, wrap only the necessary code with the `try` block, so as to only catch the desired exceptions. Use, then `inp = int(input(...))` in the `try`; use the `except` as @Adam.Er8 suggested; add a `else` block with the rest of the code (currently) inside `try`

Comment: More: you're referencing `input` as a variable name for `while ...`. This is highly discouraged as it shadows the function. More problematic is the fact that `input` variable is not defined. You actually used `inp` as the name, so update that in the loop condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this with a "infinite" loop

```
def get_num(n):
    while True:
        inp = input(f"Enter your total {n} credits : ")
        try:
            inp = int(inp)
            if inp in range(121):
                return inp
            print("Out of range")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer")
```

The only way out of the loop is to reach the `return` statement, by both avoiding a `ValueError` and successfully passing the range check.

If you don't want to nest the range check inside the `try` statement (a reasonable request), you can use a `continue` statement to skip the range check in the event of an exception.

```
def get_num(n):
    while True:
        inp = input(f"Enter your total {n} credits : ")

        try:
            inp = int(inp)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer")
            continue

        if inp in range(121):
            return inp

        print("Out of range")
```

You can also invert the range check by using an additional `continue` statement.

```
def get_num(n):
    while True:
        inp = input(f"Enter your total {n} credits : ")

        try:
            inp = int(inp)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer")
            continue

        if inp not in range(121):
            print("Out of range")
            continue

        return inp
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) at the end of your `except` clause:

```py
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a integer")
            continue
```

It will go back to the top of the `while`

Comment: then when the the given input is out of range it doesnt ask for the user to enter it again it just skip into the next variable